# Error exactly when adding share_plus to dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

This problem occurs when I launch my project, i get a very very long error, here's a part of it :
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
> .
> .
> .
> .
> .
> Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 49s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

I have tried to use the commands : flutter clean - flutter pub get
also I deleted the file .gradle and used flutter pub get
I have created a new project and added the share_plus to dependencies and I got the same error

Comment: This might help: https://gist.github.com/danielcshn/7aa57155d766d46c043fde015f054d40

Comment: it worked thank you man